# Error: called object type int is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c, random

I get this error in my C code:

```
error:called object type int is not a function or function pointer
```

I have looked all over for an answer and everywhere I have checked confirms this code should be working, so what am I missing? I want to assign random numbers to two different variables. I've commented off the errors I'm getting in my IDE. (Note: this isn’t the full code, just the relevant section)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

    int k, seed, mines, row, column, boom;
    int board[9][10];
    printf("Please enter your seed: ");
    scanf("%d", &seed); getchar();
    srand(seed);
    for(k = 1; k <= mines; k++) {
        row = rand() % 8;                 // error:called object type int is not a function or function pointer
        column = rand() % 8;              // error:called object type int is not a function or function pointer
        if(board[row][column] == 0) {
            board[row][column] = boom;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @crushendo board is a 2 dimensional  array as per code, but declared as an int now

Comment: Get the code to compile first

Comment: It sounds like you've redefined `rand` somewhere, since the compiler mentions calling an object that is not a function. Do a search for `rand` elsewhere in your code (or local header files etc).

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `for(k = 1; k <= mines; k++)`? C-style would be more `for(k = 0; k < mines; k++)`. It probably won't matter in the end, it's more about style.

Comment: Ahh, thank you Evert- that was it. rand was elsewhere in my program defined as something else by mistake, my problem is now solved. Really appreciate it

Comment: for readability, for clarity, for ability to document, one variable declaration per line.   Both 'mine' and 'boom' are used but not initialized in the posted code. Some vertical spacing, like a blank line, between code blocks greatly enhances the readability/clarity/understandability of the code.  One code statement per line make it much easier to comment the code and for us humans to understand the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
int k; seed; mines; row; column;
```

Correct the above line as follows:

```
int k, seed, mines, row, column;
```

Comment: Yes, I am. My problem is the lines that are commented

Comment: @crushendo your sample code is not showing the issue, see live demo here : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44a81337b99f325f

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, but my error has been solved. someone pointed out it sounded like rand was redefined elsewhere, and after searching through I found out that was the case, deleted the line, and the error was solved. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

rand was defined elsewhere in my program as an integer by mistake. After finding it and removing it, the error was solved

Comment: Note that the answer is pretty much in the error message: it's mostly about learning to read the error and warnings generated by a compiler.